# How can i create custom colored breadcrumb in LWC?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, css, style, lightningstylesheets

I want colored breadcrumb something like this. Please help me with designing the shape of each column (arrows shaped).
[image]

Comment: That Aura example won't apply to LWC because of Shadow DOM: you can't access a subcomponent's CSS from a parent component.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to bring the bad news but you can't customize the inner CSS of a base LWC component because of Shadow DOM.
The only thing you can do is to recreate the base component from the [SLDS Blueprint](https://lightningdesignsystem.com/components/path/#site-main-content).